# Excel VBA: Is Open Workbook an Attachment

Tags: excel, attachment, vba

Is it possible to tell if a workbook has been opened from an email attachment, rather than a drive/share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From outlook files are opened to a temp dir on your drive, you could check to see if its in that folder, VBA Source as follows

```
IsAttachment = (InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Path, "Temporary Internet Files", vbTextCompare) > 0)
```

Comment: I agree.  There isn't a "source" property.  The only way you could guess, is by looking at the path.